# Onblur of Textbox append value to textarea

Tags: jquery, blur, onblur

I want to keep appending textbox values to the texarea onblur even of textbox.

Below is my JS code :

```
    $(document).on('blur','#headLine,#line1,#line2',function(){  
        var txt = $.trim($(this).text());
        var textarea= $("#preview");
        textarea.val(textarea.val() + txt);
     });
```

But its not working. What am i doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.val()` instead of `.text()` to get the value of an `input` field:

```
$(document).on('blur','#headLine,#line1,#line2',function(){  
    var txt = $.trim($(this).val()); // Change to .val()
    var textarea= $("#preview");
    textarea.val(textarea.val() + txt); // You did it here correctly
 });
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XM4kb/) to demonstrate.

Comment: Thanks RGraham ... And one more thing i want to add each new value from textbox in a new line texarea. How can i achive it?

Comment: You can use `\n` to add a new line: `textarea.val + "\n" + txt`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
$(document).on('blur','#headLine,#line1,#line2',function(){  
var txt = $.trim($(this).val());
var textarea= $("#preview");
console.log(txt);     
textarea.val(textarea.val()+'\n'+txt);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XM4kb/4/

Comment: its nt appending the text and moreover i want to append the text in new line inside textarea each time